# Component not rendering updated controller variable on onchange event

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm very new to Visualforce and Apex development. I've been trying to create a solution on AppExchange with these two, but there is an issue I am facing. Here it goes:

```html
<apex:inputText id="form-heading"  value="{!formHeading}" styleClass="icon-input" html-placeholder="Enter Heading Text">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setvar}" reRender="outText,outHeading">
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputText>
```

This is from a component called `c:Sidebar` hosted on a page called `create`.

So the value of form heading is being updated based on the onchange event of the input.

This is my other controller on the same page called `c:FormComponent`:

```html
<apex:outputPanel id="outText">
    <script>
        x += 1;
        alert('The value of x is now: ' + x + ' {!formHeading}');
    </script>
    <apex:outputText styleClass="form-heading" style="font-size:30px;color:#3582FF;" value="{!formHeading}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

The component is getting rerendered after the onchange variable, but the value still remains the same and is driving me insane. I've added a counter to confirm that the outputText is getting rendered, and it is.

This is my controller:

```apex
public class HomeController {

    public String formHeading {get;set;}

    public HomeController(){
        formHeading = 'This is the form heading';
    }
    
    public void setvar(){     
        // system.debug('var#####'+acct.Name);
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand, what the approach is here. They all share a common controller; so after every render, the value should be updated, isn't it?!

Please help me out.

Cheers, Aadhit

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, is there a reason you are using the old Visualforce technology instead of LWC for this?

Comment: I am trying to make a full page application for appexchange, and was informed visual force was thes best choice

Comment: That doesn't sound like good advice unless you need your app to support Salesforce Classic UX. You would be much better off creating a packaged flexipage and some LWC components, assuming you only need to support LEX (Lightning Experience). Visualforce is long in the tooth and originated in the Web 1.0 era. The features grafted on to it to support "Web 2.0" are awkward to use. LWC is based on current web technologies and far easier to develop.

Comment: Got it Phil, but is there a solution to my situation on the whole?

Comment: Could you also provide me some quick start documents to start with a flexipage? It would be really helpful cheers!

Comment: Aadhit, someone else may provide a useful answer; I've not done any VF development in a couple of years (at least) so my only comment on that is that a quick look at our code base's legacy pages makes what you have done look right, at least on the face of it. As to flexipages, these are what you create using the Lightning App Builder. Create the LWCs, push them to your org, use the Lightning App Builder to create a page that uses the LWCs then pull that flexipage down from your org so you can add it to git and package it. I hope, too, that you are creating a managed 2GP!

Comment: Take a look at [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder). When using sfdx to pull metadata you will see your created pages put in the flexipages folder.

Comment: That's good Phil, my requirement is to create a form building application, that is to be full page. We're trying to build it for appexchange. Will LWC work out for that ? . The docs said visual force is good for such requirements.

Comment: LWC is the right technology to use. Visualforce is very old and was superseded by Aura then that was superseded by LWC. Be aware that there are already AppExchange packages for the use case you have stated, above, including [3B Forms](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FOmjbUAD) (declaration: developed by an ex-colleague).

Comment: (Also note that with the introduction of Dynamic Forms in Salesforce itself, I would think there's a limited shelf life for such a product - basically until Dynamic Forms come to Digital Experiences)

Comment: Got it Phil, i'll look out for LWC !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135113/discussion-between-aadhit-shanmugam-and-phil-w).

Comment: each VF component's controller, even if the same class, will reference separate objects that don't communicate with each other